# How to use \baselineskip with \blank[...]?

Tags: context

I want to add a space inbetween two sentences exactly one `baselineskip` apart. Apparently `\blank[\baselineskip]` doesn't work but if I first do `\definemeasure[x][\baselineskip]` and then do `\blank[\measure{x}]` it works. In other words:

```
\definemeasure[x][\baselineskip]
\starttext
First
\blank[\measure{x}]
Second
\stoptext
```

This confuses me. Surely, I don't need the extra define and can just put `\baselineskip` into the `blank` somehow, but everything I've tried has given me errors. Help?

Answer (score 2):

To use the value of `\baselineskip` you have to prepend `\the`:

```
\blank [\the\baselineskip]
```

Better is to use `\blank [line]`:

```
\starttext
  First
    \blank [line]
  Second
\stoptext
```

Also see: [contextgarden - \blank](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/blank)

To define you own blank distances, better use `\defineblank` instead of `\definemeasure`

```
\defineblank [somedistance] [2cm]
```

then you can use

```
\blank [somedistance]
```

Also see: [contextgarden - \defineblank](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineblank)

Comment: Why do I have to use `\the`?

Comment: What package is all of this from?  I'm completely unfamiliar iwh `\blank` and `\defineblank`

Comment: @A.Ellett ConTeXt.